# How to supress the second sidebar in Zen theme?

Tags: 7, nodes, blocks

I have nodes that include blocks in the second sidebar. When all the blocks are removed, every node's content takes up the width of the page (and extends into the sidebar region) which is what I want. When I add any block, even if it isn't displaying on that specific node, the sidebar is no longer suppressed.

I also have to re-save every block I add in the second sidebar region, because if not, it displays the title 2x and it displays on every node, regardless of what it is configured for. So for example, if my block of "related links" displays only on node x, it will show also on node y UNLESS I re-save the block configuration.

I have not found anything in my searches here and on Google (most want to add to a sidebar not remove it), and I just don't know where to even start looking for what could be wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to structure => blocks, and move those blocks in another region, voila second sidebar suppressed. You may want to change the regions altogether but that gets into theme templates and such...